# createUserWithEmailAndPassword Firebase Auth automatic login problem with React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a react application connected to the firebase realtime database and firebase authentication. I have three levels of users with different privileges. I have a superadmin, admin, and basic user. Also I have a form and a table on my React app to create new users in auth and write some other metadata with that newly created user UID into my realtime database node. For instance, if I have an admin@admin.com user with higher privileges and I want to create a new user blabla@bla.com with it, it automatically logs me in as that newly created user with low privileges and that user cannot write data into database. Also I have a delete user function that deletes my current user and logs me out.
How can I be able to solve that problem? Is there any way around that?

this is my register function:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    // e.preventDefault();

    const workersRef = ref(rtdb, "workers/");
    const newWorkerId = push(workersRef).key;

    if (newWorkerId !== null) {

      try {
        signUp(email, password)
          .then(async (userCredential) => {

            const newUser = userCredential.user;
            const userUID = userCredential.user.uid;

            const newWorkerRef = child(workersRef, userUID.toString());

            await set(newWorkerRef, {
              name: name,
              surname: surname,
              address: address,
              phone: phone,
              uid: userUID,
            });
ate(ref(rtdb, `workers/${userUID}/`), updates);
            }
          }).catch((error) => {
            // An error occurred during registration
            console.error("Registration error:", error);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding worker: ", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

and this is my delete function:

````
    const confirmDelete = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");

    if (confirmDelete) {
      const dbRef = databaseRef(rtdb, `workers/${id}/`);

      {user?.uid === id && user?.delete()}

      remove(dbRef)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Child node successfully deleted");
          console.log(id);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error("Error deleting child node:", error);
        });
    }
  };```
````

Comment: Create the new user using the Firebase Admin SDK on a backend.  You won't be able to do this purely within the frontend of your app because of the behavior you're observing (there is no workaround).